# matplotlib // space between subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot images (in the 1st row) along with some diagrams (the 2nd and 3rd rows) using `subplots` from `matplotlib.pyplot`. However, `imshow` fucntion adds some additional white space around images I can't get rid of. Here is my code and the plot I'm getting:

```
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (16, 14)
_, axes = plt.subplots(3, 3)

axes[0][0].imshow(image)
axes[0][0].set_title('title')
axes[0][0].set_xticklabels(list())
axes[0][0].set_yticklabels(list())
axes[0][0].grid(False)

axes[0][1].imshow(image)
axes[0][1].set_title('title')
axes[0][1].set_xticklabels(list())
axes[0][1].set_yticklabels(list())
axes[0][1].grid(False)

axes[0][2].imshow(image)
axes[0][2].set_title('title')
axes[0][2].set_xticklabels(list())
axes[0][2].set_yticklabels(list())
axes[0][2].grid(False)

plt.savefig(file_name, bbox_inches='tight')
```

in the plot below you can clearly see that there is significantly more space between the 1st and 2nd rows:

[image: the plot I'm getting]

I would like to have an equal space between all subplots. What would be the easiest way to do this?

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Best,
Alexey

Answer (score 0):

This is because `imshow` is showing the image with square pixels. If the image as a ratio of e.g. 16:9, the subplot will be reshaped to fit the image size. They will therefore have a different shape from the other subplots (see the [imshow documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow.html) for more info).

From here, you have two solutions:

- decrease the figure height in order to reduce manually the vertical space between subplots
- prevent `imshow` to resize the axes based on the images. For this you can set the aspect ratio to automatic `aspect="auto"`, and the image will fit the existing axes

Comment: aspect="auto" leads to equal space but for the price of image distortion

Comment: In this case, only the first solution works for you: if you try with `rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (16, 11)` for instance, is it better? (you need to play around with the figure height).

Comment: yes, it is getting better, but I'm not completely happy with the result... it's very strange somehow, seems to be a very basic thing